# Convert single integer variable to a list of numbers (for example +/-3) with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, math

I was hoping to convert a single integer variable (coming in from a POST parameter) into a list, within a range of the original number, for example +/-3, using PHP.

So if var = 5
using PHP, output is = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8

or if var = 17
output is = 14,15,16,17,18,19,20

This is early guesswork, but I was thinking something like this:

```
<?php 

$single = $_POST['number'];

$mc = $single - 3;
$mb = $single - 2;
$ma = $single - 1;

$pa = $single + 1;
$pb = $single + 2;
$pc = $single + 3;

$list = [$mc, $mb, $ma, $single, $pa, $pb, $pc,]

echo $list

?>
```

But it is just printing 'Array',

New to PHP, feel like I am overlooking a lot of things. Is it possible to assemble an array like this? Is there a quicker way to do what I'm trying?

Was hoping to do more like +/-30 .. was hoping there might be a shortcut / function that could help?

Comment: `echo` will print `Array()` for arrays, try using `print_r($list)`.

Comment: `$single = (int)$_POST['number'];` just to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) for this.

```
<?php
$num   = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'num', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$range = 3;

if($num !== false) {
    $result = range($num-$range, $num+$range);
    echo implode(',', $result);
}
```

Output when (num is 2 and range is 3):

```
-1,0,1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `implode` function after that.

```
$list = [$mc, $mb, $ma, $single, $pa, $pb, $pc];

echo implode(',', $list);
```

If you want to extend it for variable range too.

```
$single = 17;
$range = 3;
$data = range($single - $range, $single + $range);
echo implode(',', $data);
```

Comment: thanks Jitendra, its working! Is there a quicker way to do the maths above? For example if I wanted to do +/-20 .. and didn't want to write out every $single-20, $single -19, $single-18, etc

Answer (score 0):

> Was hoping to do more like +/-30 .. was hoping there might be a shortcut / function that could help?

Yes, use a loop. Because you know the range you want, you can use a [`for`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop:

**NOTE:** This code works with negative numbers, too.

```
$range = 3; // your given range
$value = (int)$_POST['number'];
$result = [];
$result[] = $value;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $range; $i++){
     $result[] = $value - $i ;
     $result[] = $value + $i;  
}

// Sort array and then output:

sort($result, SORT_NUMERIC);
 
print implode(', ', $result);// outputs a sorted list of values 
// Value = -2
// -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1
//
// Value = 5
// 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```